# eregi_replace depricated how to replace correctly?

Tags: php, eregi

I just discovered that the `eregi` is deprecated, and that `preg replace` works differently. 
How would you translate this?

```
$text = eregi_replace("\\[img\\]([^\\[]*)\\[/img\\]", "", $text);
```

Comment: Start by reading the [list of differences](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) between the two different syntax rules. And a nice quide [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch13_02.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
$text = preg_replace("/\\[img\\]([^\\[]*)\\[/img\\]/i", "", $text);
```

1. encode your pattern between `/` and `/i`
2. use `preg_replace` instead of `eregi_replace`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works:

```
$text = preg_replace("#\[img\](.+?)\[/img\]#is", "", $text);
```